# Batch replace string without a FOR loop

Tags: string, batch-file, for-loop, replace

I have the following string

```
set str=aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,dddd
```

I need to replace everything from the first `,` (comma) till the end of string. but I don't know how the string starts.

I can't use the * wildcard as it is not in the start of string, so something like that -

```
set str=%str:,*=% >>>> Will not work
```

***Any ideas ? it must be in a batch script***

Comment: Is this "aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,dddd" a string or set?

Comment: Aree you asking how to replace ",bbbbb,ccccc,dddd" this portion in you string "aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,dddd"? and you don't know starting of string!!!

Comment: Yes. I wat str to be "aaaaa" and I don't know that it start like that. All I know it ends with a `,` (comma) and I cant do it in a FOR loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple and fast solution that avoids a FOR loop: use search and replace to inject a concatenated REM command at each comma :-)

```
@echo off
set str=aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,dddd
set "str=%str:,="&rem %
echo str=%str%
```

**Explanation**

Here is the the important line of code, before any expansion takes place:

```
set "str=%str:,="&rem %
```

And here is what the line is transformed into after variable expansion:

```
set "str=aaaaa"&rem bbbbb"&rem ccccc"&rem dddd
```

It becomes a SET statement, followed by a REM statement. The `&` operator allows you to combine multiple commands on one line. There is only one REM statement because everything after the first REM is considered part of the remark.

Comment: Haha, I didn't know about that, but it's a million times better than mine :) Mine was fun to make though, but I think I knew there must have been a better way, oh well.

Comment: @Eli - Explanation added :)

Comment: Now I know even better why I hate batch :-)

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything after the first comma you can use

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set str=aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,dddd
for /f "delims=," %%a in ("%str%") do (
set str=%%a
echo !str!
)
pause >nul
```

To replace, simply strip it and append the new string on the end

```
    set str=%%a,new,string
```

***Update***

This will do the same, but without a `for` loop

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set str=aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,dddd
set strip=%str%
set length=0
set start=0
set new=
:loop
if defined strip (
set strip=!strip:~1!
set /a length+=1
goto :loop
)
:comma
if %length% gtr 0 (
call :add !start!
if "!char!"=="," (
goto :break
) else (
set new=!new!!char!
set /a length-=1
set /a start+=1
goto comma
)
)

:break
echo %new%
pause >nul

:add
set char=!str:~%1,1!
```

Comment: I need it without a FOR LOOP

Comment: @Eli I have updated my answer, considerably more difficult, but it doesn't use any `for` loops.

Comment: I can use other delimier like space of semicolun, if it would make it easier.

Comment: No worries, not that I can think of unfortunately. I doesn't matter what delimeter you use, because you would still have to go through the entire string to find it anyways, glad it's working though :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why couldn't you use a for loop?

Comment: The batch is running in some tool and when the tool interates the parmeter in the for some parameter won't be interpated and I get null.

Comment: There is a much simpler and faster solution that avoids a FOR loop - see my [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14320626/1012053).

Comment: You should probably accept Dave's answer as it's much better than mine.